# Convert mask (&H80) to integer in VB

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to do some Visual Basic coding and have some masked variables like this:

```
aux1 = &H80
aux2 = &H40
```

I later need to use them in other places, and it would be more convenient to have them as Integers - any idea how to do that?

Comment: This is no mask, this is Hexadecimal... if you declared aux1 as Integer you can use it anywhere in your code like an integer...

Answer (score 2):

`&H80` and `&H40` **are** integers. The hexadecimal notation perhaps improves readability, that's all.

Specifying them as hexadecimal or in [denary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) has absolutely no effect on the runtime behaviour.

(You can use logical AND on `aux1` and `aux2` if you want to use them as masks.)